# How to launch safari and open URL from iOS app in private mode

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

`UIApplication.sharedApplication.openURL(NSURL.URLWithString("http://www.google.com"))`
opens Safari with the designated URL, but is it possible to force the private (incognito) mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that,there only can call the "http://"url scheme for safari,so i think there no kind magic:(

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry...it's pretty hard for a non-English user try to answer a question